# Simulating Object.defineProperties in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

How can I simulate Javascript's Object.defineProperties in Typescript? I would like to do something like this using Typescript syntax:

```
Object.defineProperties(someObject.prototype,
   {
       property: {get: function() { return value; } },
       anotherProperty {get: function() { return somethingElse; } }
   });
```

Any pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to "simulate" it? Doesn't the code work as is?

Comment: Notice that neither `property` nor `anotherProperty` as you defined them are functions, they're getter properties.

Comment: Oh right, you did write `Cesium.defineProperties`. Why did you not use `Object.defineProperties`?

Comment: Honestly, because I was trying to keep it as close to the original code as possible. Seems that I have no better option but to change it to Object though

Comment: I don't know Cesium. Does it have a `defineProperties` method? What is the `Cesium` object?

Comment: Cesium is a library. "An open-source JavaScript library for world-class 3D globes and maps" - cesiumjs.org
It does not have a defineProperties method. I believe the person who originally wrote it meant to reference the Object.defineProperties() function.

Comment: updated question to be more streamlined and bypass the confusion with using Cesium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all you need is just getters (setters works similarly).

It can be checked on the [TS Playground page](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_myProp%3A%20string%20%3D%20%22myPropValue%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get%20myProp()%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22get%20myProp%3A%20%22%20%2B%20this._myProp)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this._myProp%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20set%20myProp(value%3A%20string)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20alert(%22set%20myProp%3A%20%22%20%2B%20value)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this._myProp%20%3D%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20myObj%20%3D%20new%20MyClass()%3B%0D%0Aconst%20myPropValue%20%3D%20myObj.myProp%3B%0D%0AmyObj.myProp%20%3D%20%22newValue%22%3B%0D%0Aconst%20myPropNewValue%20%3D%20myObj.myProp%3B).

Here is a simple example of it:

```
class MyClass {
    private _myProp: string = "myPropValue";
    get myProp(): string {
        alert("get myProp: " + this._myProp);

        return this._myProp;
    }
    set myProp(value: string) {
        alert("set myProp: " + value);

        this._myProp = value;
    }
}

const myObj = new MyClass();
const myPropValue = myObj.myProp;
myObj.myProp = "newValue";
const myPropNewValue = myObj.myProp;
```

More information can be found in the [TS Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic doesn't need to change, the DefineProperties functions can stay, you just need to let typescript know how the object looks

Firstly, create an interface for the resulting object. These getters can look like normal readonly properties in the interface.

Then define a templary variable as type  and attach all properties / getters

Finally create a new, typed variable that references your already setup object with all getters
const myObjectWithGetters = tempGetterObj